# Build and link a local library in a Xamarin project

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, nuget

So I'm trying to automate the builds for a Xamarin project and integrate it to our company's CI pipeline. I'm not really familiar with .NET/Xamarin building process, but I've done it before following the [**really short** guide for CI they have](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/intro_to_ci/).

I'm using a standalone macOS build server (since we have to build iOS `.ipa` with XCode) with Visual Studio for this purpose.

Turns out, this time, we have a local dependency (some [library](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap) we needed to slightly modify) integrated as a git-submodule on the project. The developers are all using the IDE for this and it loads/unloads and resolves all the dependencies without problem (or at least they told me that): they just have to hit the "play" button and it simply builds everything.

I'm trying to find a way to the same programmatically (using `msbuild` on the CI server) and here's where the problems start: so far, every time I run

```
$ nuget restore projectApp.sln
[...] # first get the project packages
$ msbuild \
    /p:Configuration="Debug" \
    /p:Platform="iPhone" \
    /p:BuildIpa=true \
    /p:IpaPackageDir="./Builds" \
    /t:Build project.sln
```

... I get ~250 `"are you missing an assembly reference?"` errors. I assumed that meant the library dependencies were not found, so I tried resolving them with `nuget`:

```
$ nuget restore TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap.sln
[...]
```

But running `msbuild` again returns the exact same output:

```
[...]
Project "/Users/builder/project/projectApp.sln" (1) is building "/Users/builder/project/projectApp/projectApp.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
Project "/Users/builder/project/projectApp/projectApp.csproj" (2) is building "/Users/builder/project/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap.csproj" (3:2) on node 1 (default targets).
CoreCompile:
[...]
"/Users/builder/project/projectApp.sln" (Build target) (1) ->
"/Users/builder/project/projectApp/projectApp.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
"/Users/builder/project/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap.csproj" (default target) (3:2) ->
(CoreCompile target) ->
Api/Google/GmsDirection/GmsDirection.cs(2,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/Users/builder/project/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap.csproj]
Api/Google/GmsDirection/GmsDirection.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/builder/project/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap.csproj]
```

First of all, I want to know if there's a way to build the library fork on a different, internal pipeline and serve it + handle it in the project using nuget (like I'd do with the original version).

And then, in case that is too much *over-engineering*, how to properly build locally the whole project (**including the library**) and link it all together.

Comment: You should be able to compile using msbuild on the command line. The Newtonsoft namespace error suggests that the project is using a NuGet package. Are they using a packages.config file or a project.json file or a PackageReference in the project itself? A packages.config file should work using nuget restore. However a PackageReference would need a recent NuGet version for it to be restored correctly. Another thing to check would be the references in the TK.CustomMap.csproj to see if they are correct.

Comment: @MattWard there's a `project/projectApp/packages.config` indeed inside our project. 

I wrote just a couple of lines of the error, but there's even some about "namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found", odd. And all those being spitted out  by the library we have as submodule, locally. No idea how to check the refs. in https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/blob/Development/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap.csproj#L40-L87 and fix them if they're not sound :/

Comment: The TK.CustomMap.csproj project is using a project.json file. I would check the project.lock.json file is being generated next to the project.json file. My guess is that you are using an old nuget that ships with Mono and does not support project.json files so is ignoring these projects.

Comment: If the project.lock.json file is being generated then I would check the location where the project is being checked out to. There is hard coded path defined to the project.lock.json file which may affect the build - https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/blob/Development/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap.nuget.targets#L6 - Although I do not see this file being imported so it may not be used.

Comment: Woah, running `nuget`, it reports back version 2.12. I thought it updated with the jump to Visual Studio. I used homebrew just now to get nuget 4.0. and all the missing assembly reference errors are gone. Neat! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Later versions of Mono ship with a more recent NuGet version. I currently have Mono 5.4 installed and it includes NuGet 4.3.